# Riddle: What am I? Part 2

Tags: riddle

Although a human shape I wear,
Mother I never had;
And though no sense nor life I share,
in finest silks I’m clad.
By every miss I’m valued much,
beloved and highly prized;
Still my cruel fate is such by boys I am often despised.

Comment: I answered it, but really, you need to come up with original ones, not ones that you can easily search for on the internet (I googled after answering to find that indeed it is available on several sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> Doll

Why?

> Dolls have human shapes, but no mother. You typically dress dolls up in fine clothes. Boys (especially older brothers) tend to rip the heads off dolls.